# Webbrowser find dialog for a text within an html element

Tags: c#, winforms, search, webbrowser-control, textrange

I try to have the find dialog feature in my webbroser control, it should search several words (forward) and highlight them. 
I tried the following code  from [this MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b8c9d5d5-8d85-49ee-91e3-0753a6ead023/webbrowser-find-dialog?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

```
    private bool FindFirst(string text)
    {
        IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)browserInstance.Document;
        IHTMLSelectionObject sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
        sel.empty(); // get an empty selection, so we start from the beginning
        IHTMLTxtRange rng = (IHTMLTxtRange)sel.createRange();
        if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
        {
            rng.select();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

However this code and the code in the original question search the entire document and use  `range = body.createTextRange()` to create a range, I would like to search within a specific element (for example just text in a specific `div`)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding [moveToElementText(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the code. It moves the text range so that the start and end positions of the range encompass the text in the given element.

```
  bool FindFirst(HtmlElement elem, string text)
  {
        if (elem.Document != null)
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc =
                elem.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            IHTMLSelectionObject sel = doc.selection as IHTMLSelectionObject;
            sel.empty();

            IHTMLTxtRange rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
           // MoveToElement causes the search begins from the element
            rng.moveToElementText(elem.DomElement as IHTMLElement);
            if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
            {
                rng.select();
                rng.scrollIntoView(true);
                return true;
            }               
        }
        return false;
  }
   public bool FindNext(HtmlElement elem, string text)
    {
        if (elem.Document != null)
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc =
                elem.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            IHTMLSelectionObject sel = doc.selection as IHTMLSelectionObject;              
            IHTMLTxtRange rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            rng.collapse(false);
            if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
            {
                rng.select();
                rng.scrollIntoView(true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```